# Redirect user on specified route

Tags: redirection, services

I know we can easily redirect a path to another path with Redirect module, but what I want to do is more complicated,  my condition is when the user has a specified IP and the route is matched with to a specified path redirect it.

Pseudo code what I'm looking for is

```
if $path='xxxxx' and $user_ip = 'yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy' redirect to 'zzzzz'
```

how I can implement this, what I need is where is the best place to implement this?

Comment: If this is for anonymous traffic then implement a middleware. A good example is [BanMiddleware](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21ban%21src%21BanMiddleware.php/class/BanMiddleware/8.6.x), only that you would return a redirect response instead of a 403 response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the routes (conditionally based on IP) by creating an event subscriber or by [using a RouteSubscriber](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21EventSubscriber%21RouteSubscriber.php/class/RouteSubscriber/8.6.x).  You should also look at [altering existing routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones).

Comment: I've got your point .could you provide more details, please?